# error while trying to open a Word application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com

i am getting the following error while trying to open a Microsoft word document from within a c# VS.NET 2010 windows forms application.

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

I am using a Windows 7 64 bit OS.

I have added the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in the project > references

i have set the Build platform to target x86 enviroment

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
var wordApp = new Word.Application() {Visible = true}; <-- ERROR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems that you have not MS Office installed on that machine.

Comment: I have Microsoft word Starter 2010 installed on my PC. Should that make a difference?

Comment: is word installed in 32 or 64 bits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Word starter edition [doesn't support automation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/worddev/thread/2e235d2f-4fca-4d99-98c2-1dc8d92561cb).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either

- Word is not (correctly) installed on the machine, or
- the platform target of your application is not set to x86 (you can do so under Project -> Properties).

Both are required for Word automation to work on an x64 system.