# C# Microsoft Interop Word - Class not registered but Word is installed

Tags: c#, ms-word, runtime-error, office-interop, office-automation

so I've tried to run this application on a different machine from my own and I started to get some nasty *"RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED"* exceptions. I checked for the installed Word versions and I found out there were 2: a 2013 one and a 2021 one.
I checked and saw the 2013 one was not activated so I just uninstalled it.
Problem is now it get the hated *"REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG"* exception as soon as I try to instantiate a "new Word.Application".

What am I doing wrong?
Here some screens of the setups: [I have the references to assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLlkE.png), [I have Microsoft Office installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlcBf.png), and [my Word is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DWJQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably windows registry records were messed or corrupted after uninstalling an old Word/Office version. You need to re-install or repair the existing Office version to refresh the windows registry keys in case of any key is missing. For example, you may find a lot of similar posts like [error while trying to open a Word application in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909771/error-while-trying-to-open-a-word-application-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Seems like reinstalling (as restarting) keeps being the omnipotent problem-solving answer. It is now working, thanks!